# reshape df with timeseries to have n-1 value

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series

Given I have the current df. I am trying to create a new column with the n-1 value.

```
Date        id  Val
2012-03-01  a    1
2012-06-01  a    2
2012-09-01  a    3
2012-12-01  a    4
2013-03-01  a    5
2013-06-01  a    6
2013-09-01  a    7
2013-12-01  a    8
2012-03-01  b    100
2012-06-01  b    101
2012-09-01  b    102
2012-12-01  b    103
2013-03-01  b    104
2013-06-01  b    105
2013-09-01  b    106
2013-12-01  b    107
```

Expected Result

```
Date        id  Val     Val_n_minus_1
2012-03-01  a    1      NA
2012-06-01  a    2      1
2012-09-01  a    3      2
2012-12-01  a    4      3
2013-03-01  a    5      4
2013-06-01  a    6      5
2013-09-01  a    7      6
2013-12-01  a    8      7
2012-03-01  b    100    NA
2012-06-01  b    101    100
2012-09-01  b    102    101
2012-12-01  b    103    102
2013-03-01  b    104    103
2013-06-01  b    105    104
2013-09-01  b    106    105
2013-12-01  b    107    106
```

Please note that I have more columns but want to have this transformation only to a specific column without losing the others.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself.

```
df['Valu_n_minus_1'] = df.sort_values(by=['Date']).groupby('id')['Val'].shift()
```

Comment: My answer too late: `df.groupby('id')['Val'].shift()` :)